# Use var from function in another file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a file (function.js) with a function.
I have a another file where I want to call this function

My problem is that i'm trying to call a variable inside this function but I don't know how can I ?

Function.js

```
function getAllIssueForSCII(){
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://***.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=project=SCII',   
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': "Basic ***"
        }
    };

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        request(options, function (error, response, data) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log('JIRA login success!!')
                var json = JSON.parse(data);    /!\ Call this variable        
            } else {
                console.log('error: ' + response.statusCode + ': ' + data.statusMessage)
            }

        })
    })
}
module.exports.getAllIssueForSCII = getAllIssueForSCII;
```

Index.js

```
var functions = require('./functions.js')

functions.getAllIssueForSCII();
console.log(json) // Error;
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: you cannot return from an asynchronous callback

Comment: You can't access local variables inside another function.

Comment: 1. in your Promise, call `resolve(JSON.parse(data));` 2. outside, use `functions.getAllIssueForSCII().then(res => console.log(res));`